# Can not access to my private cosmos DB from python codes

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have setup a cosmosDB database as a private one so it has a private endpoint in one of my private subnet. I have come up with some python coes to get stat from database as follow:

```
>>> import azure.cosmos.cosmos_client as cosmos_client
import azure.cosmos.errors as errors
import azure.cosmos.http_constants as http_constants>>> >>>
>>> import os
>>> url = os.environ['ACCOUNT_URI']
>>> key = os.environ['ACCOUNT_KEY']
>>> client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient(url, {'masterKey': key})
>>> for x in client.list_databases():
...     print(x)
```

But above codes gives me below error:

```
raise exceptions.CosmosHttpResponseError(message=data, response=response)
azure.cosmos.exceptions.CosmosHttpResponseError: Status code: 401
{"odata.error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":{"lang":"en-us","value":"Authorization header doesn't confirm to the required format. Please verify and try again.\r\nActivityId: 750a7ec5-9cdb-4ee9-a2c6-498eaddc9253, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.11.0 Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0\nRequestID:750a7ec5-9cdb-4ee9-a2c6-498eaddc9253\n"}}}
```

I am not sure what is wrong but I think this is not due to my internal firewalls or rules or been permission issues but it cloud be due to authorization headers when I establish the connection... Any clue would be appreciated..

Comment: Any help or cluer would be apprecited!

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved. Customer was trying to access the Table API using the Core (SQL) SDK.

Comment: Upvoted! In this case how the Table API should be called?

Comment: Use this library. https://pypi.org/project/azure-cosmosdb-table/